# bash - how to dump all elements in array within usage

Tags: bash, shell

I'd like to dump my array to the user so they can see what the mappings would look like. I tried so with this statement `printf '%s\n' "${cluster_to_endpoint[@]}"` I'm trying to dump it within my usage function below, however I'm not getting the output i'm expecting.

Code in progress:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

usage () {
    echo "Usage: $0 -o oldcluster -n newcluster"
    printf '%s\n' "${cluster_to_endpoint[@]}"
}

while getopts ":o:n:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    o) old="$OPTARG";;
    n) new="$OPTARG";;
    *) usage
       exit 1
       ;;
  esac
done


# Mapping
declare -A cluster_to_endpoint=(
        [c1]=foobar2-01.us-east-1.my.com
        [c2]=foobar2-02.us-east-1.my.com
        [c3]=foobar2-03.us-east-1.my.com
        [c4]=foobar2-04.us-east-1.my.com)

# Echo info
echo "Source cluster:${cluster_to_endpoint[$old]}"
echo "Target cluster:${cluster_to_endpoint[$new]}"
```

Output:

```
-bash-4.1$ ./tst.sh -h
Usage: ./tst.sh -o oldcluster -n newcluster
```

Expecting:

```
Usage: ./tst.sh -o oldcluster -n newcluster

    [c1]=foobar2-01.us-east-1.my.com
    [c2]=foobar2-02.us-east-1.my.com
    [c3]=foobar2-03.us-east-1.my.com
    [c4]=foobar2-04.us-east-1.my.com
```

Comment: You would have a better chance of getting the output you expect if you create the array *before* you try to print it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is executed from top to bottom, and when it enters the while loop, calls usage, which tries to print your array but it has not yet been initialized.

Put the declare statement before any access to it.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your `usage` shell function before initializing the array `cluster_to_endpoint`.

Move the `declare` statement to before handling the command line.

In addition to that, the subscripts in an array must evaluate to integer values, and can't therefore be `c1` etc. as you have. **EDIT** Apparently this is how you do associative arrays in Bash version 4+. Older Bash needs to use ordinary arrays (`declare -a`) with integer subscripts.

Comment: `declare -A` declares an associative array in Bash 4+. They are keyed by strings.

Comment: That's true, forgot to say I had to change to `-a` for the `bash` I was running. If it works in your version of `bash`, then go with that. Ping @noober

Comment: `tr` isn't necessary; `printf` as given will print each element of the array on a separate line.

Comment: @chepner So it does! I wonder what made it *not* do that when I ran it before? Oh, I used `[*]`.